# Sort a Hexadecimal number using Swift 4 and greater

Tags: ios, iphone, swift4.2, swift5, xcode11

I have strings coming like

```
[
 "71ADDC23D2048",
 "9BF4F631EBA69",
 "B123454F4F631EBA69",
 "123454F4F6345FGT"
]
```

My current code to sorting is  :

```
// Sorting the Tans
func sortByTagID(arrayTags:[TansIDS],orderBy:String) -> [TansIDS] {

    if orderBy.uppercased() == OrderBy.Ascending {
        let sortedArray = arrayTags.sorted {String($0.trans-id!).localizedStandardCompare(String($1.trans-id!)) == .orderedAscending}
        return sortedArray
    }
    else {
        let sortedArray = arrayTags.sorted {String($0.trans-id!).localizedStandardCompare(String($1.trans-id!)) == .orderedDescending}
        return sortedArray
    }

}
```

Please let me know if there is a better way to sort than this ? Since when I am comparing with other platform(Android) its not same.

Comment: What is `TansIDS`? What is the expected result? And the `G` in the 4th string is not valid hexdecimal.

Comment: TansID's - Just the array of ID's expected for sorting.

Comment: Solve it by making it  "localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare"

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

```
func sortByTagID(arrayTags:[TansIDS],orderBy:String) -> [TansIDS] {

    if orderBy.uppercased() == OrderBy.Ascending {
        let sortedArray = arrayTags.sorted {String($0.trans-id!) < String($1.trans-id!)}
        return sortedArray
    }
    else {
        let sortedArray = arrayTags.sorted {String($0.trans-id!) > String($1.trans-id!)}
        return sortedArray
    }
}
```

Output Ascending:

```
[
 "123454F4F6345FGT",
 "71ADDC23D2048",
 "9BF4F631EBA69",
 "B123454F4F631EBA69"
]
```

Output Descending:

```
[
 "B123454F4F631EBA69",
 "9BF4F631EBA69",
 "71ADDC23D2048",
 "123454F4F6345FGT"
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply . Found the solution for it by change it to "localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare"